# Not getting c4267 warning for few lines in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I had a task of removing all warnings in one of the project.
At one place in code I had following line.

```
dims[0] = children.size();
```

Where dims is '**int**' array and children is a '**vector**', so `size_t` is assigned to `int`. I am compiling this code on `VS2015`.

Ideally the above assignment should generate a warning

```
"C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data"
```

But I don't get any such warning. So there are zero warnings in the code.

Now I convert warning **4267** into an error using '`/we4267`' and then start getting error for above lines.

I am confuse why compile didn't showed any warning in first place.

Thanking you all for your help.

Comment: are you compiling with -Wall?

Comment: No there is no such flag specified. But at rest of the locations I was getting C4267 warning. Except few like above.

Comment: pretty sure Warning C4267 only gets printed if you're compiling with -Wall (which just tells the compiler to actually print all warnings, which it won't do by default) or -w3 (It's a level-3 warning).

Comment: You'll only get it when you target x64, /we4267 is not necessary.

Comment: ys target is x64

Comment: Below are all the compiler flags with which the file gets compiled.Since /WX is present- warning should have been displayed, No? 
But its only when I add /we4267 that compiler shout.

cl.exe /nologo /openmp /J /WX /we4013 /we4022 /we4024 /we4047 /we4273 /we4305 /we4715 /we4003 /we4029 /we4031 /we4172 /we4297 /we4553 /we4098 /we4716 /we4477 /we4133 /Gy /Zc:forScope  /EHsc /MD /GF /Z7  /Od /EHsc /Dport2pcnt /Dpcnt /Dport264 /Dport2littleend /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /DWIN8664 /DWINNT /D_CPYRTYR_=2017 /DDEBUG -DUSES_QT_GUI -DWIN8664 -DUSE_NORMAL_PRINTF -DUSE_PYTHON_INTERFACE

Answer (score 0):

I found that when /WX compiler option is added then some warnings, in my case C4267, are suppressed. Either adding compiler option /WX /Wall or removing them all together shows error/warning C4267. In my case I was getting error in other modules as there was no warning related compiler option add but the module where I didn't got C4267 warning, had compiler option /WX.

Its just that there is no documentation regarding this(or may be I was not able to find one).